# Использование протокола Error

Tags: ios, swift

Какой из представленных вариантов недопустим в Swift(использование протокола Error)?

Вариант 1

```
enum EnumError: Error {  
    case error  
}
```

Вариант 2

```
struct StructError: Error {  
    let error: String  
}
```

Вариант 3

```
 class ClassError: Error {  
        let error = "Error"  
    }
```

Вариант 4

```
extension Int: Error {  
    var error: String { "\(self)" }  
}
```

Comment: дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1061851/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Выберите правильное утверждение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1061851/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1):

Все варианты допустимы. Из документации:

> Any type that declares conformance to the Error protocol can be used
>   to represent an error in Swift’s error handling system. Because the
>   Error protocol has no requirements of its own, you can declare
>   conformance on any custom type you create.